# NSDateFormatter converts time

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have **NSDate** with (2012-11-14 08:08:16 +0000) and want to show hours, minutes and seconds.

So i used **NSDateFormatter**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss aaa"];
```

My phone time is (10:08:16) but i want toshow not phone time but that NSDate which i have, however after

```
[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]
```

It gives me **10:08:16** but i want **08:08:16** 
How i could just show a time ?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to show the time in UTC not local time?

Comment: Well yes i get UTC time from server and want to show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show raw time (UTC) then set timezone by hand:

`[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];`

That should do it.